# Ошибка при сравнении char

Tags: java, сравнение

У меня возникает ошибка при сравнении чара. 
По идее условие должно выполнятся только если первая буква слова не гласная, но оно выполняется на все буквы.
Использование StringBuffer обязательно.
Подскажите, где ошибка

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class main {
    public static int i, n;
    public static boolean orly = false;
    public static StringBuffer input, b, tokenStr;
    public static StringTokenizer out;
    public static char aChar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new StringBuffer(
                "This Str3in5g r$ep)lace E`xa.,mp\\le ashosa how ^t-o replace ane char oпривет from String");
        b = new StringBuffer(input.toString().replaceAll("[^a-z A-Z А-Я а-я]",
                ""));
        if (b.toString().trim().length() != 0) {
            out = new StringTokenizer(b.toString());
            System.out.println("Начальная строка - " + input.toString());
            System.out.println("Форматированая строка - " + b.toString());
            n = (out.countTokens());
            for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
                tokenStr = new StringBuffer(out.nextToken());
                aChar = (tokenStr.charAt(0));
                System.out.println(aChar);
                if ((tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'a') || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'A')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'e')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'E')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'i')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'I')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'o')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'O')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'u')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'U')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'y')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Y')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'а')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'А')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'е')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Е')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'ё')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Ё')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'и')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'И')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'о')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'О')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'у')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'У')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'ы')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Ы')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'э')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Э')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'ю')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Ю')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'я')
                        || (tokenStr.charAt(0) != 'Я')) {
                    b.delete(b.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()),
                            b.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()) + tokenStr.length()
                                    + 1);
                    System.out.println(b);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Пустая строка");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Яркий пример, как не нужно делать :-)

Comment: Скажите, как надо?

Comment: Исправил код. Все работает

Comment: @antoxa2584, Представьте ситуацию, что вам нужно еще больше символов исключать, вы так и будите это условие множить? =)

В вашем случае регистр не важен, значит можно использовать функцию "UpperCase" или "LowerCase", приводя ваш первый символ к верхнему или нижнему регистру. Все символы с которыми нужно произвести сравнение лучше поместить в массив, например в string, и произвести сравнение на наличие вашего первого символа в этом массиве, например через функции Contain, или pos. Если символа там нет, то делать то-то, а если есть - то делать это...

Comment: PS: Java язык не знаю, но принцип построения логики обычно используется такой.

Comment: думается мне, эту задачу легче решить, если решать с другой стороны. Проверять, входит ли первый символ строки в строку "AeEiIoOuUyYаАеЕёЁиИоОуУыЫэЭюЮяЯ". Код будет просто на порядок проще и модифицировать легче (если завтра понадобиться добавить гласные какого то другого языка).

Comment: @KoVadim, именно это я и пытался описать. Но ему не нужен регистр букв, следовательно массив букв можно сократить в двое, сравнивая заглавные буквы массива с заглавной буквой первого символа его строки.

Comment: видимо Ваш комментарий я не совсем внимательно почитал.

Comment: По сути мы просто создадим еще один цикл, чтобы проверить первый символ. Не очень разумно.

Comment: @antoxa2584: а чтобы проверить, является ли число квадратом, вы тоже будете сравнивать со списком квадратов? Оставьте loop unrolling компилятору, у него это лучше получается. Пока вы не убедились, что в этом месте проблема, не оптимизируйте. Преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед (ц).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  По идее условие должно выполнятся только если первая буква слова гласная
> ```

```
  if ((tokenStr.charAt(0)!='a') ||...
```

вроде бы тут наоборот

Comment: Да
Моя ошибка.
Поправил вопрос)